# Auto refresh of table rows based on events, in rails using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

i am currently working on a rails application. brief regarding the application is as follow:

i am allowing user to edit data(to database) in html table(using javascript and ajax calls)

what i want is, when a user updates a cell(and saves to db), other users should get this updated information without a page refresh.

i can use a javascript timer function that will load new data at every few seconds, but i want this to be event driven(say when a user updates any data) since calling server controller at some seconds is not efficient.

please suggest some better way of doing this. also some guidance on how to achieve this in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by websocket. By example you can use the webservice [pusher](http://pusher.com/)

In open source you can have :

- [Faye](https://github.com/faye/faye)
- [Slanger](https://github.com/stevegraham/slanger)

Comment: thnx shingara, is there any other open-source/free library for websockets?

Comment: I update my answer with some open source project like pusher.

Comment: thnx again, can you also give some details on how can i start using pusher or slanger for auto refreshing html table? it would be great if you provide some guidance/hint for the same.